# Join tables in SQLiteQueryBuilder setTables

Tags: android, sqlite

Now I have following code:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb=new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect={"0 _id","lang","value"};
    String sqlTables="gloss";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);

    Cursor c=db.query(GL_TABLE, sqlSelect, "value like '%"+inputText+"%'", null, null, null, null, "20");
```

It is working perfect. Here this code is taking only one table. How to take data from 3 tables which are related with each other(entry is main node, sense is child of entry and gloss is child of sense):

> entry(id,ent_seq); sense(id,fk); gloss(id,fk,lang,value);

Is it possible to do this with setTables? If it is, please give some suggestions how to do this.

**I have done as @Anders8 said:**

```
public Cursor getJoinedInfo(String lookingFor)
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: looking up info");

    SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor;
    String query;

    query="SELECT " +
            " e.id," +
            " s.id," +
            " s.fk," +
            " g.id," +
            " g.fk," +
            " g.lang," +
            " g.lang" +
            " FROM entry e" +
            "     INNER JOIN sense s ON e.id = s.fk" +
            "     INNER JOIN gloss g ON s.id = g.fk" +
            " WHERE g.value like '%"+lookingFor+"%'";

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: query = \n" + query.replace(", ",",\n  "));
    cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DB: query complete");

    return cursor;      
}
```

It is giving this error:

> 08-09 22:26:16.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9842): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

What should I do?

Comment: The best way I can think of is to do a union of a query on each table.  But I'm not an SQL expert so I'll keep this as a comment in case someone knows a better way.

Comment: union of a query on each table? What does it mean?

Comment: A UNION sql command will combine the result from two other queries.  You use "query1 UNION query2".  So you could do "SELECT FROM table1 blah blah blah UNION SELECT FROM table2 blah blah blah UNION SELECT FROM table3 blah blah blah"

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be something like this:

```
public Cursor getJoinedInfo(String lookingFor)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "DB: looking up info");

    Cursor cursor;
    String query;

    query="SELECT " +
            " a.fieldName1," +
            " a.fieldName2," +
            " b.fieldName3," +
            " c.fieldName4" +
            " FROM tableName1 a" +
            "     INNER JOIN tableName2 b ON a.someKeyInA = b.someKeyInB" +
            "     INNER JOIN tableName3 c ON a.someOtherKeyInA = c.someKeyInC" +
            " WHERE a.FieldName ='" + lookingFor +"'";
    Log.d(TAG, "DB: query = \n" + query.replace(", ",",\n  "));
    cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);
    Log.d(TAG, "DB: query complete");

    return cursor;      
}
```

Obviously, build the query you need. ;)

Comment: It is giving error:08-09 22:26:16.632: E/AndroidRuntime(9842): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: I don't know what you're _doing_ with the results of this query. But in Android, some of the listview stuff REQUIRES that you have an id field called "_id". You have "id". If you're trying to send it to a listview, that will be problematic.

Answer (score -1):

You can [perform a join in SQLite](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/joins/). This will allow you to join all or only certain attributes from the tables you are working from into one final relation. That way you can select exactly what you're looking for.

I don't know what's in the data set or what you're looking for so I cannot write the query but I will say this - your best approach is to (1) write the query as a string (2) execute a raw database query using that string and (3) using the cursor to select the data from the result.